# adding elements to the array creates a new array instead of adding

Tags: php, arrays

i have been trying to add two elements to my array which is always been created. but after i add those elements it creates new element instead adding to the existing one.

**code**

```
<?php
Continues from top....
while($finalRes = mysql_fetch_assoc($excute))
            {
            $tables[] = $finalRes;
            }

            if(mysql_num_rows($excute) != 0){

                $report = new Report();
                $ID = substr($table,11);
                $log = $report->projecteden($ID);
                $a=0;
                $b=0;
                if(property_exists($log, 'counts')){  
                    foreach ($log->counts as $m)      
                    {
                        $UNIQUES = $m->count;                
                        $NON-UNIQUES = $m->ucount;
                        $a += $UNIQUES;
                        $b += $NON-UNIQUES;
                    }
                    $tables['UNIQUES'] = $a;
                    $tables[] = $tables['UNIQUES'];
                    $tables['NON-UNIQUES'] = $b;
                    $tables[] = $tables['NON-UNIQUES'];
                }
            }
            var_dump($tables);
?>
```

**var_dump result**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'ID' => string '105' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'R158' (length=11)
      'accountname' => string 'DDD' (length=3)
      'accountID' => string '1' (length=1)
      'stat' => string '2' (length=1)
      'total_impr' => string '207' (length=3)
      'min(a.timestamp)' => string '2014-05-16 05:38:01' (length=19)
      'max(a.timestamp)' => string '2015-01-22 05:50:41' (length=19)
  'UNIQUES' => int 45
  'NON-UNIQUES' => int 13
```

as u can see UNIQUES and NON-UNIQUES are not aligned, can any help me to add UNIQUES and NON-UNIQUES to the same $tables array

Comment: did you try using `array_push()`?

Comment: yeah i did... it did the same thing actually..

Comment: I think the problem might be that you have an extra curly brace? 

`while($finalRes = mysql_fetch_assoc($excute))
            {
            $tables[] = $finalRes;
            }`

The while loop is ending here no? and I think you need it to continue in order to iterate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign index like this

```
your code....
$tables[0]['UNIQUES'] = $a;
$tables[0]['NON-UNIQUES'] = $b;
your code ....
```

if you want to reemove 0 index then

```
$tables = $tables[0];
```

Comment: thanks.. it worked i accept your answer.. one small thing.. furthermore is there a way i could add this to specific location in the array

Comment: for moving index you have to reassign the values

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
  while($finalRes = mysql_fetch_assoc($excute)){
        $temp = $finalRes;

        if(mysql_num_rows($excute) != 0){

            $report = new Report();
            $ID = substr($table,11);
            $log = $report->projecteden($ID);
            $a=0;
            $b=0;
            if(property_exists($log, 'counts')){  
                foreach ($log->counts as $m)      
                {
                    $UNIQUES = $m->count;                
                    $NON-UNIQUES = $m->ucount;
                    $a += $UNIQUES;
                    $b += $NON-UNIQUES;
                }
                array_merge($temp ,array('UNIQUES' => $a));
                array_merge($temp ,array('NON-UNIQUES' => $b));
                $tables[] = $temp;
            }
        }
 }
        var_dump($tables);
```

Comment: is it not dumping anything?

Answer (score 0):

1) you can create new temp array and add element to that array.
2) use array_merge to merge element of temp array to our main array with key & value pair.
3) use can use below code. it is working fine.

```
while($finalRes = mysql_fetch_assoc($excute))
{
   $tables[] = $finalRes;
}

if(mysql_num_rows($excute) != 0){
   $report = new Report();
   $ID = substr($table,11);
   $log = $report->projecteden($ID);
   $a=0;
   $b=0;

if(property_exists($log, 'counts')){  
    foreach ($log->counts as $m){
         $UNIQUES = $m->count;             
         $NON-UNIQUES = $m->ucount;
         $a += $UNIQUES;
         $b += $NON-UNIQUES;
    }

    $temp = array('UNIQUES' => $a,'NON-UNIQUES' => $b);
    $tables = array_merge($tables,$temp);
}
}
var_dump($tables);
```